# How to make site responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am having trouble making the footer, row section, and h1 in the header responsive for my site. The footer and row section have three column layouts, with the section having boxes. When I resize the page, the text goes all over the place and the h1 disappears. The three boxes stack on top of each other and I want them to be under each other when the page gets resized. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ComPack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/challenge.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
      <img src="images/06926FRH.jpg" alt="">
      <h1 class="com">ComPack</h1>
  </header>

   <nav>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">Solutions</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Locations</a>
     <a href="#">Support</a>
   </nav>

   <section class="row">
       <article id="results">
           <h2>Results</h2>
           <p>Unde quae quidem earum, at, ullam officiis minus! Facilis incidunt impedit cum unde quae, neque debitis reiciendis perspiciatis asperiores dolor totam culpa, soluta sapiente veritatis. Accusantium illum quisquam, repellendus temporibus!</p>
       </article>

       <article id="partners">
           <h2>Partners</h2>
           <p>Adipisci soluta, voluptas perferendis illo, quas culpa doloribus? Nulla quibusdam, eveniet consectetur enim voluptatibus nam quos minus, aliquam voluptatum quis. Velit nesciunt quam, quidem praesentium laudantium nostrum nobis iusto animi.</p>
       </article>

       <article id="future">
           <h2>Future</h2>
           <p>Nam recusandae nihil harum animi excepturi nulla qui laborum sed illo repudiandae numquam quibusdam eaque, eius culpa unde pariatur suscipit inventore quos iure saepe at dolor fuga ea. Aperiam, ex.</p>
       </article>
   </section>
   <footer class="row2">
      <div id="copyright">
       <p><small>Copyright &copy; 2017 ComPack, Inc.</small></p>
       </div>

       <div id="contactUs">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Technical Support</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="resources">
          <h3>Resources</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cumque amet aspernatur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aut perspiciatis consequuntur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accusantium nihil illum</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>

.com {
  top: -34rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
}
nav {
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: auto;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: beige;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222;
  color: beige;
}

footer a {
  color: beige;
}

header {
  color: #36a;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#contactUs a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

#resources a:hover {
  color: lightcoral;
}

#results {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem .2rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  margin-left: 9rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  flex: 1;
}
#partners {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem .2rem 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 3.5rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  flex: 1;
}
#future {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  margin-top: -8rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  padding: 0rem 1.1rem .2rem 1.5rem;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.42);
  flex: 1;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
}

#copyright {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 5.3rem;
}

#resources {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20.5rem;
  margin-top: -8rem;
}

#contactUs {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 45rem;
  margin-top: .2rem;
}

.row2:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #copyright {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #contactUs {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #resources {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: you have a few issues within your CSS. you declare a with of 27% and later for the very same class a width of 300px. The 300px will always apply then because it is written last. for full responsivness try to avoid a width in pixels. And of course, only declare one width or use min/max-width.

Comment: Ok I got rid of the percentage for width and just kept the 300px but the boxes are still overlapping when I resize the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your articles need to be in a flex container for them to be put in a layout correctly. Take a look at this, I removed the row class (You can keep it) and changed it to container, which I only gave this property display: flex;

https://jsfiddle.net/4kzpjhe6/ You can see it here, it isn't fully corrected but is a better place to start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ComPack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/challenge.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amiri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
      <img src="images/06926FRH.jpg" alt="">
      <h1 class="com">ComPack</h1>
  </header>

   <nav>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">Solutions</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Locations</a>
     <a href="#">Support</a>
   </nav>

   <section class="container">
       <article id="results">
           <h2>Results</h2>
           <p>Unde quae quidem earum, at, ullam officiis minus! Facilis incidunt impedit cum unde quae, neque debitis reiciendis perspiciatis asperiores dolor totam culpa, soluta sapiente veritatis. Accusantium illum quisquam, repellendus temporibus!</p>
       </article>

       <article id="partners">
           <h2>Partners</h2>
           <p>Adipisci soluta, voluptas perferendis illo, quas culpa doloribus? Nulla quibusdam, eveniet consectetur enim voluptatibus nam quos minus, aliquam voluptatum quis. Velit nesciunt quam, quidem praesentium laudantium nostrum nobis iusto animi.</p>
       </article>

       <article id="future">
           <h2>Future</h2>
           <p>Nam recusandae nihil harum animi excepturi nulla qui laborum sed illo repudiandae numquam quibusdam eaque, eius culpa unde pariatur suscipit inventore quos iure saepe at dolor fuga ea. Aperiam, ex.</p>
       </article>
   </section>
   <footer class="row2">
      <div id="copyright">
       <p><small>Copyright &copy; 2017 ComPack, Inc.</small></p>
       </div>

       <div id="contactUs">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Technical Support</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="resources">
          <h3>Resources</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cumque amet aspernatur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aut perspiciatis consequuntur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accusantium nihil illum</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made those edits but the boxes are not under each other and I still need help with that for the footer as well.

Comment: To make them be under each other use the css property flex-direction: column;  in the flex container. You could wrap this in a media query.